# xarray: coords conversion to datetime64

Tags: python-xarray, netcdf4, datetimeindex

I have a NetCDF4 file that i'm handling using xarray.
The dataset has a "time" coordinate as dtype=object and i would like to convert it ot datetime64 in order to simplify plotting of the variables contained in the file.
My plan was to create a new time coordinate called "time1" using

```
ds.assign_coords(time1=pd.to_datetime(ds.time.values,infer_datetime_format=True))
```

and then delete the old one. But i get a new coordinate still as dtype=object.
[here's how the new dataset looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWSWn.png)

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problems like this can often be solved with something like:

`ds['time'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(ds['time'].values)`

Here's an example, prior to applying the above line:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (time: 93)
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) object 1593128700000000000 ... 1593211500000000000
Data variables:
    val      (time) float64 4.23 4.25 4.24 4.23 4.24 ... 4.08 4.07 4.07 4.07
```

and after:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (time: 93)
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2020-06-25T23:45:00 ... 2020-06-26T22:45:00
Data variables:
    val      (time) float64 4.23 4.25 4.24 4.23 4.24 ... 4.08 4.07 4.07 4.07
```

Comment: OMG, such a simple solution. Why didn't i think of that?
Thanks Dan!

Comment: Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. See: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more info.

Comment: @Dan do you mind explaining why this is necessary? When I do `pd.to_xarray()`, my dataframe contains `datetime64`, but the xarray output contains `pd.Timestamp` objects. It's not clear why a recast is happening.

Comment: I needed to execute the same twice. In first execution it was still obejct (seemed like big number) and then in the second time it was converted to datetime64 object.